# CakePHP 3 - populate select dropdown with data from custom table

Tags: cakephp-3.0

So I started looking at CakePHP, and I'm just doing a few test cases to see if CakePHP will cater for all my needs.

I have a custom table (Table name: roles):

```
id  role    sub_site
1   Role 1    0
2   Role 2    0
3   Role 3    0
4   Role 4    0
5   Role 1    1
```

In my controller (User controler) I have the following code based on all the feedback here.

```
$this->loadModel("roles");
$rolesList = $this->roles->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('sub_site' => '0'),
        'fields' => array('id', 'role')
));
$this->set(compact('rolesList'));


I have the following in the view

$this->Form->input('role', array('label'=>false, 
               'div'=>false, 
               'type'=>'select', 
               'empty'=>'-- select one --', 
               'options'=>$rolesList));
```

Yet the output looks like this:

```
<select name="role" required="required" id="role">
<option value="">-- select one --</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

All I want is the output as follows:

```
<select name="role" required="required" id="role">
<option value="">-- select one --</option>
<option value="1">Role 1</option>
<option value="2">Role 2</option>
<option value="3">Role 3</option>
<option value="4">Role 4</option>
</select>
```

Please indicate what is wrong here as this is suppose to be simple to just populate?

Comment: seems like all good..post the debug value of $rolesList , how the data are actually coming ?

Comment: sorry but how do I get the debug values, I'm new to this framework :-(

Comment: Hope this helps: @ManoharKhadka
SELECT 
  roles.id AS `roles__id`, 
  roles.role AS `roles__role` 
FROM 
  roles roles 
WHERE 
  sub_site = 0


rolesList(array)

    11
    22
    33
    44

CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_site` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `role`, `sub_site`) VALUES
(1, 'Recruiter', 0),
(2, 'Moderator', 0),
(3, 'Line Manager', 0),
(4, 'Admin', 0),
(5, 'Super Admin', 1);

Comment: Check this doc: [Finding Key/Value Pairs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs) you can pass yur own keyField and valueField

Comment: Nope tried that. Still only getting the ID's as the option values and option fields.

$this->set('rolesList', $this->roles->find('list', [`keyField` => 'id', `valueField` => 'role']));

<select name="role" required="required" id="role"><option value="">-- select one --</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>

Comment: Found the solution. The keyfield and valuefield in the array was not single quotes. I've changed that and now the select option is correct. this is good news. Thanks @JacekBBudzynski for the link, this solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting results using this method. In my controller:

```
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Transfers');
$make=$articles->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id','valueField' => 'make']);
$this->set('make',$make);
```

and then in view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('make',['type'=>'select','options'=>$make ,'empty'=>'-Select Make-','class'=>'form-control','templateVars'=>['class'=>'col-md-4']]);
```

Hope you will get results.